# Sanitize $_POST and $_GET array inputs OOP

Tags: php, sanitization

I have this code from a class method that I want to use to treat the data before pass them to the database. I'm not sure on how to proceed, this because usually I prefer to use ajax and a non OOP controller to sanitize the various data. I'm not sure if use `filter_var_array` or `filter_input_array` to achieve this task. If anyone has a suggestion about this task, I will appreciate it.

Here is an example of my code:

```php
<?php

class UserRegistration{

  public function registration($data = null){
    echo $this->view->registrationForm();

    if( isset($_POST['register']) ){
      $data = [
        $_POST['username'],
        $_POST['email'],
        password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost'=>11])
      ];

      if( $this->sanitizeData($data) ){
        echo $this->view->registrationSuccess();
      }
    }

  }

  private function sanitizeData(array $data){
    $args = ['username'=> FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 'email'=> FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL, 'password'=> FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ];
    $sanitized_data = filter_var_array($data, $args);
    return $sanitized_data;
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: Just use prepared statements.

Comment: I use them, but for security, I always prefer to sanitize the user inputted data before saving into db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need sanitize data before saving it to the database. More info here
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95325/input-sanitization-vs-output-sanitization

Comment: Why? 
In my experience also if I use the prepared statements, I always prefer to sanitize data before saving them into the database. I will read the suggested link, thanks

Comment: Because you altering incoming data. 
You need to use a prepared statement to avoid sql injections
And sanitize data when displaying the data to a user to avoid xss attack

Comment: Ok, so it will not be a risk if I avoid to sanitize the user inputted data. I will follow your advice

Comment: No risk if you won't forget to sanitize data when displaying it. To be honest sanitizing output data should be enabled by default. Otherwise, the chance to forget sanitize it close to 100%. In modern frameworks, it enabled by default and no sanitizing input data.

Comment: Ok, I was worried about SQL injection, in fact I always used the prepared statement with data sanitization, I never had a problem, but I will try to make the next webapp by skipping this security measure.